# Unable to install tensorflow-addons on windows

Tags: tensorflow

`pip install tensorflow-addons` throws `ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow-addons`. I tried installing various versions but keep getting the same error. I am using windows and my tensorflow version is 2.5.0-rc1. Tried downloading the  .whl file and then install but didn't succeed. I need the AdamW optimizer.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to upgrade `pip` and then select appropriate version of the `tensorflow-addons` as shown below

```
TensorFlow Addons              TensorFlow            Python

tfa-nightly                     2.3, 2.4           3.6, 3.7, 3.8
tensorflow-addons-0.12.1        2.3, 2.4           3.6, 3.7, 3.8
tensorflow-addons-0.11.2        2.2, 2.3           3.5, 3.6, 3.7, 3.8
tensorflow-addons-0.10.0           2.2             3.5, 3.6, 3.7, 3.8
```

For more details you can refer [Python Op Compatibility Matrix](https://github.com/tensorflow/addons#python-op-compatibility-matrix).